# How to search for a window in perl

Tags: perl

I want to search for a window in perl. If the window is not found i want to again start searching for it in 2 seconds. 
How to do this?
I know i can find a window using FindWindowLike()

Answer (score 3):

```
use Win32::GuiTest 'FindWindowLike';
use strict;
use warnings;

my @windows;
until ( @windows = FindWindowLike(...) ) {
    sleep 2;
}
```

though you may be better off using WaitWindowLike.